# Probability that two independent Poisson random variables with same paramter are equal

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, power-series, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

> What is the probability that two independent Poisson random variables with parameter $\lambda<\infty$ have the same value?

My solution:

\begin{align}
P = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{e^{-\lambda T} (\lambda T)^i}{i !} \right)^2 = e^{-2\lambda T} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{ (\lambda T)^{2i}}{(i !)^2} 
\end{align}

I don't know how to continue from here. How can I evaluate the above summation? Can you help?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thanks. But they are independent.

Comment: Your sum should start at $0$. And are you looking for a closed-form? I doubt there is one.

Comment: Hint: The modified Bessel function $$I_0(t) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty  \frac{4^{-k} t^{2k}}{(k!)^2} $$

Comment: Do you want an exact answer (in which case you'll end up looking at Bessel functions) or an approximate one? If an approximate one, about how large is $\lambda$?

Comment: @MichaelLugo Yes, I need an exact answer. $\lambda$ may be very large, but it is finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be Poisson-distributed with mean $\lambda_1$, and let $Y$, independent of $X$, be Poisson-distributed with mean $\lambda_2$.  Then $X-Y$ has the [Skellam distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution) with parameters $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.  In particular if $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda$, then

$$ P(X=Y) = P(X-Y = 0) = e^{-2\lambda} I_0(2\lambda)$$

where $I_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind.

Comment: Thanks. Can you add the final value?

Comment: Well, that will depend on what $\lambda$ is.

Comment: The answer is $I_0(2 \lambda T)$.