# Find the probability $P(X<Y)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

> > Suppose $X$ and $Y$ be two independent Poisson $(\lambda)$ random variables. Find $P(X<Y)$.

**My attempt** $:$

\begin{align*}P(X<Y) &= \sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{y=x+1}^{\infty} P(X=x,Y=y) \\
&=  \sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{y=x+1}^{\infty} P(X=x) P(Y=y) \\
&=  e^{-2\lambda} \sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac {{\lambda}^x} {x!} \sum\limits_{y=x+1}^{\infty} \frac {{\lambda}^y} {y!} \\
&=  e^{-2\lambda} \sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty}\left( \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!} - \frac{\lambda^x}{x!} \sum\limits_{y=0}^x \frac {\lambda^y}{y!} \right) \\
&= e^{-2\lambda} -  e^{-2\lambda} \sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} \left( {{\frac {{\lambda}^x} {x!}} \sum\limits_{y=0}^{x} {\frac {{\lambda}^y} {y!}}} \right)
\end{align*}

Now how do I calculate $$\sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac {{\lambda}^x} {x!} \sum\limits_{y=0}^{x} \frac {{\lambda}^y} {y!} \right)$$ Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you edit your question there is some error in your latex formatting

Comment: Please somebody point out where my error was.

Comment: please check if the edit is correct.

Comment: Yeah it is correct.

Comment: Simpler: By symmetry, $P(X<Y)=P(X>Y)$ hence $P(X<Y)=\frac12-\frac12P(X=Y)$ with $$P(X=Y)=e^{-2\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^{2n}}{(n!)^2}$$ for which there is no simpler expression (except, rather circularly, by identifying the sum as a value of a special function defined as the sum of this series).

Comment: @Did Yes but it's sometimes convenient to recognize the special function if you're interested in using someone else's computer code to get an actual number out. Take for instance the special functions $\sin$ and $\cos$

Comment: @Mark The page you link to in your answer below is actually a good start to see the problem: note how people there call "Hint" or "Answer" the mere mention of the **name** of a series **which the OP already computed on their own**.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from. It's reminiscent of this old Feynman clip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ga_7j72CVlc
 I agree that knowing the name does not constitute an answer or even a hint. I was just saying that knowing the common name of an object allows you to leverage the historical mathematical capital surrounding the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the special case of $X$ and $Y$ being identically distributed, you have

$$P(X < Y) + P(Y < X) + P(Y = X) = 1$$
$$2 P(X < Y) + P(X = Y) = 1$$
$$ P( X < Y) = 1/2 (1 - P(X = Y))$$

So it reduces to computing $P(X =Y)$ whose computation appears here [Probability that two independent Poisson random variables with same paramter are equal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2185262/probability-that-two-independent-poisson-random-variables-with-same-paramter-are)

Comment: Yeah @Mark I have found it myself just now without seeing your answer.